# Sync indexes from other databases

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have two physical databases servers with several schemas.  The both physical servers are same databases structures such as tables, settings etc. but the database environment is different. Recently when I compare with actual database settings, the indexes of these two database servers was not matching. Nearly half of the indexes was missing.

I need to sync those indexes and make it as same as actual database.I didn't get clear steps. So is there any steps or possibility to sync the missing indexes? . Please share your thoughts.

Comment: How are you going to decide which indexes are correct from each schema; are you treating one as the correct 'master' and want to make the other look the same? Are the indexes that do exist on both identical, or do they all need to be dropped and recreated? Your schema modifications should be under source control to prevent this sort of issue.

Comment: @AlexPoole : Yes you are right. I am treating a correct'Master" data and comparing with other Databases servers. tables and  Indexes are identical but the indexes alone missing for some tables. I cannot manually recreate those missing index,because of huge tables. Is the automatated way to sync or I need to replace index section alone with correct 'Master' Server.

Comment: You can't copy the index data from one server to another, if that's what you mean; that wouldn't really make sense. Even if the data is identical and static I don't think it's possible, not least as `rowids` would still be different; and if it isn't then the index would be invalid anyway. You'd have to run `create index` statements on the databases that are missing them.

Comment: If you have Toad you can use `Database->Compare->Schemas` to generate the DDL required to make two schemas equal.

Comment: Or use `dbms_metadata.get_ddl` calls to get all the index creation statements, which I imagine is what Toad does under the hood; SQL Developer does the same. Or use data pump to recreate them.

Comment: `> I cannot manually recreate those missing index,because of huge tables.`

@rocky, if creating indexes by running `create index ...` (possibly via data pump) is not an option for you. Then there is an option to clone the whole tablespaces or the whole database.

What exactly is the issue with re-creating the indexes? It takes long (you can use parallel option; or build them partition by partition); or it`s blocking something (you can use `online` option)?

Comment: @Yavor: There is no issues with recreating indexes by running create index. The only concern is my database has nearly 400 tables with missing indexs issues. I run by running create index option. My three days of productivity will be lost. Thats why i am searching for better option.

Comment: @Yavor: As you said in previous comment, clone whole tablespaces is better option. I will try :)

Answer (score 1):

You can import indexes using Oracle Data Pump. E.g. could be something like: `impdp include=indexes` (so that it only imports the indexes).

Comment: This is likely to be the simplest approach - easier than extracting and manually running the DDL for each index, and maybe faster (less downtime) with parallelism and multiple workers. But this still builds the indexes from their DDL, it doesn't import the actual index 'data', which seems to be what the OP was hoping for.

Comment: If desired: Data Pump can generate the DDL too (sqlfile=... option).